# How to change UNIX user password using passwd if user is stored in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, pam, passwd, nss

I'm trying to setup `libnss-mysql` and `libpam-mysql`. So far everything has been working. I can use `id` to get information about the users stored in my databas. `getent passwd` is working, as well. However, `getent shadow` is not. Additionally, I'm not able to change the passwords of users that are stored in the database using `passwd`. Is there a way to fix these issues?

Btw., I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 as a Minimal Virtual Machine.

*Update*

The only configuration files I change were `/etc/nss-mysql.conf`, `/etc/nss-mysql-root.conf` and `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. I'm pretty sure the former two are correct. Since they simply configure how the database is accessed. I only added the word "mysql" to the following three lines of the latter one:

```
passwd: compat mysql
groups: compat mysql
shadow: compat mysql
```

I didn't touch any other configuration file. If one of you needs to see any other file, please let me know, because right now I have no idea which other configuration file might be of interest.

Comment: Maybe. But we can't tell without seeing your current configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `getent shadow` won't return anything unless you are root.

You need to change the PAM config in /etc/pam.d to use the mysql PAM module.

After that you will be able to change passwords with the normal `passwd` command.

Comment: I was `root` when I executed `getent shadow`. It returned all the users specified in `/etc/passwd`, however, not the ones stored in the database. Are there any resources on how I properly configure `pam` to work with MySQL?